# Faster render json to view in Rails grape

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, render, ruby-grape

I'm working on cache huge json(about 60k lines), is there a better way to render it to view than simple "return data" ?
I don't want to paginate it, any ideas?
It takes about 1 second to show it on page, I would like to make it faster.

Comment: You can enable gzip on your http server, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried http://msgpack.org/ ?

Like Json but faster!

Grape have a msg pack integration : https://github.com/rosylilly/grape-msgpack